# Google Sheets - Search / Replace by matching values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics

I have 2 sheets in Google sheets.

1 list is a master export from Google analytics, contain post URLs, pageviews, time on page etc, 5,000 rows or so, 6 columns.

The other list, is a list of specific URLS, approx. 500, with the URLs only.

So in list 2, these values are duplicated in list 1, but scattered amongst the 5000 rows.

What I want to do, is identiy the values in list 2 that match list 1, and delete all of the items (urls) that do not match from list 1, which will give me the data (pageviews, time etc).

So, essentially say, "hey, check list 1 for everything that's in list 2, and if the row doesn't match the URL from list 2, delete it".

Comment: Please share a sample sheet so that we can more easily help you.  Also, is it essential that the rows be deleted from the original sheet, or is it okay if we just create a new list of the data, either on the same sheet or in a new sheet/tab, but filtered to remove all of the rows you want removed?

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*You can use a `TextFinder` to find matching URLs and remove the rows.*

#### Code Example:

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("master-sheet-id");
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("url-sheet-id");

  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var urlRange = "A1:A100";
  
  var rangeOfUrls = sheet2.getRange(urlRange).getValues();  
  var range = sheet2.getDataRange();  
  var listOfRows = [];
  
  rangeOfUrls.forEach(function(url) {
    var x = range.createTextFinder(url).findAll();    
    x.forEach(function(instance) {
      listOfRows.push(instance.getRow());      
    });
  });
  
  listOfRows.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  
  listOfRows.forEach(function(row) {
    sheet1.deleteRow(row);
  });
}
```

**Rundown of this script:**

- Open both the master and the URL list Spreadsheets
- Loop through each url in the range defined by `urlRange` and use a `TextFinder` to get all the rows.
- Push each row number to an array
- Sort the array containing the list of rows in descending order
- Delete the rows from the master sheet

**Things to remember:**

- You will need to put in your master sheet and URL sheet IDs.
- You will need to specify the sheet names for your master sheet and URL sheet
- You will need to change the range defined in `urlRange` to be the column inside your URL sheet which contains the URL list

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: If you are not sure how to create a bound script, please let me know.